# How to read a date of birth from a txt file and check if older than 18

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains a list of athletes with their date of birth.

I'm trying to figure out how I can read from the text file only the athletes who are on the "elite" team and who are older than 18.

I have figured out how to get only the "elite" athletes, but I can't think of how to solve the age problem.

The birthdates are created separated integers day, month and year

This is the code I've been working on

```
public void readUngdomElite() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        //file to read
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("medlemlist.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (sCurrentLine.contains("elite")) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }}

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code gets me all the athletes who are elite, but I want the elite athletes who are older than 18.

Comment: Please add an example of your file to the question

Comment: You should provide a sample of data that can be used to answer your question.

Comment: What attempts have you made to parse out an age from `sCurrentLine`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should provide a .txt file content. But to check if team is older than 18 years you can use this method. Date there is String type and `YYYY-MM-dd` format.

```
    public boolean isAdult(String birthday) {
        String[] parts = birthday.split("-");
        if (parts.length==3) {
            int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

            String currentDate = getCurrentDate();
            if (!currentDate.isEmpty() && currentDate.contains("-")) {
                String[] parts2 = currentDate.split("-");
                if (parts2.length==3) {
                    int cYear = Integer.parseInt(parts2[0]);
                    int cMonth = Integer.parseInt(parts2[1]);
                    int cDay = Integer.parseInt(parts2[2]);

                    int rYear = cYear - year;
                    int rMonth = cMonth - month;
                    int rDay = cDay - day;

                    if (rMonth<0)
                        rYear = rYear - 1;
                    else if (rMonth == 0 && rDay<0)
                        rYear = rYear - 1;
                    if (rYear > 17)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private String getCurrentDate() {
        Date todayDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String todayString = formatter.format(todayDate);
        return (todayString!=null)? todayString : "";
    }
```

Feel free to edit the code as you need

Comment: Why not use `java.time` libraries?

Comment: `java.time` libraries was added just since Java 8

Comment: Yes and Java 8 was released several years ago. Java 9 was just released

Answer (score 0):

The new [Date and Time library](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) provides you with convenient methods such as:

`LocalDate.of(2015, 02, 20);`

`LocalDate.parse("2015-02-20");`

`Period.between(firstDate, secondDate)`

With that it shouldn't be too hard to find an age based on how your string looks.

```
String str = "12 01 1996";
String[] arr = str.split(" ");
LocalDate birth = LocalDate.of(Integer.valueOf(arr[2]), Integer.valueOf(arr[1]), Integer.valueOf(arr[0]));
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
if (Period.between(birth, now).getYears() > 18) {
    System.out.println("major");
} else {
    System.out.println("minor");
}
```